# Converting Date to .ICS Format (1 Hour Out)

Tags: php, date, date-conversion

I'm currently in the process of trying to generate a .ics calendar file using PHP.

It works fine apart from the date. The below comes out as 18:45:00 instead of 17:45:00. I'm guessing this may be to do with Daylight Saving Time (DST). Has anyone encountered something similar before?

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: For compatibility with the .ics format it needs to be outputed as a time stamp.

```
$start_time = '2014-11-13 17:45:00';

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_time, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$datestart = $start->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use format instead of getTimestamp.

`$datestart = $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: I should have mentioned, it needs to be converted to a timestamp in order for it to be compatible with the .ics format.